# Shell scripting, print all the record count from the file with one day back data

Tags: shell-script, files, date

I have a directory like "20170811".
There are many files in this directory.
I want to record count of all the files with date of previous day.
Means, when i ran this script it will show record count according to Today-1

I want to print only previous date and record count.
Thanks
Aman

Comment: *record count* ? perhaps, files count

Comment: record count, each file contains some records.

Comment: You are storing previous date's files under today's date directory ? Carefully specify the requirements.

Comment: And when you say record count, what it is that you consider a record also needs explicit mention.

Comment: No, we have a different dates of directories individually, i want to find out record for yesterday date. Suppose if i want to run script todays, but script must contains records count for one day back.

Comment: Hi Rakesh,    I want to print like ;- Today-1  Record count from files which contains some data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, records are the lines in a file.

Running something like this may work for you.

```
grep '' *$(date -d '-1day' '+%Y%m%d')* | wc -l
```

Here we are grepping for any files in the current directory that have yesterdays date in it's name and then counting number of lines in all such files.

Comment: let me check this command rohit,

Comment: hi rohit, suppose i have directory,  AB/20170810/20170811/. But i want to run this command only when i am in "AB" directory, it will automatically define directory that , i want to find the data for previous day

Comment: Hi Rohit, I want to add some modificaion like, i have a different types of directories, i need to put only directory name and command will count all the records from those files which comes under that directory.